# Emacs ERC login

Tags: emacs, elisp, irc, dot-emacs

When entering IRC with `M-erc`, Emacs remembers the last used server name and port. You can accept, hitting enter, or change those parameters.

As for the user name, it defaults to system user name and not to the last used one. 
How can I have Emacs to suggest the last user name or a predefined one?

Comment: Hm... for me, it uses my GMail email, but I don't think I've ever configured anything in it... Which probably means it takes it from some mail-related setting, perhaps you should try looking in that direction? Actually, try `C-h f erc-compute-full-name` and see if that helps, it seems to try to look in many different places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness I propose an answer allowing to store both your account ID and password.

### Solution 1: Store account in the Emacs init file

Append/add to your Emacs init file:

```
(setq erc-nick "my-nice-id")  
(setq erc-password "my-nice-pw")
```

Note: You will get an `y/n` query to accept default password (i.e. my-nice-pw).

### Solution 2: Store account in an external storage file

To avoid sharing your sensitive data  when/if you share your Emacs init file or to store your data in a more secure directory, you can store your account data in an external file. Append/add to your Emacs init file:

```
(let ((acc (read-lines "~/.my-erc-account")))
  (setq erc-nick (car acc))  
  (setq erc-password (nth 1 acc)))
```

where ".my-erc-account" contains:

```
"my-nice-id"
"my-nice-pw"
```

Place and name this file as it is more convenient for you and adjust the `read-lines` argument accordingly.

Comment: I used your second way and i get read-lines variable is void ... Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @bersam: What do you read in the echo area if typing: `(read-lines "path/to/erc-file")` followed by `C-x C-e` ?

Comment: i found out that i should declare read-lines in my emacs,     `(defun read-lines (filePath)
      "Return a list of lines of a file at filePath."
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert-file-contents filePath)
        (split-string (buffer-string) "\n" t)))`

Comment: @bersam: you need to append the code snippet in your Emacs init file.

Comment: According to: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/erc.html#Introduction 
You should be able to put the settings in:
~/.el/.ercrc.el 
But I just tried it with the above lines and it didn't pick up the values automagically.

So might need to add something to .emacs to load it, or something.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `erc` <kbd>RET</kbd>

(n.b. ERC has a *lot* of customisation options, so you'll probably find some interesting things in there...)

Answer (score 1):

I created a very simple Elisp function to simply the process of ERC login: http://wenshanren.org/?p=314

Comment: Yes, I knew this; `(erc ...)` function is well documented, but the problem with it is that you go straight to the server/account you passed as parameters. I was instead looking for _suggestions_, that is changing `M-erc` default suggestions with custom ones.

Comment: @antonio Emacs has three functions: `erc-compute-server`, `erc-compute-port`, `erc-compute-nick`, to get the default values for server, port and nickname. `erc-compute-server` uses variable `erc-default-server`, `erc-compute-port` uses variable `erc-default-port`, but there is no corresponding variable for `erc-compute-nick` (see the links in the last part of `erc`'s doc-string). You may want to create your own variable and change the `erc` function.

Comment: And that's why my solution uses `(setq erc-nick "my-nice-id")`. 
Anyway `(erc-compute-...)` functions  work after issuing  `M-erc`, I need to set default suggested values for erc before loading it.